# Equilibrium and the derivative of potential energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, soft-question, calculus, statics

In his Classical Mechanics popular lectures ( Lecture 3, at the beginning)  , Susskind illustrates the idea of a stationary quantity using an example involving the notion of equilibrium.

Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3apIZCpmdls

He states that " object M is in equilibrium at point x" is equilalent to " the derivative of V(x) - potential energy function - with respect to x is equal to 0".

This implies ( as is explained in a short MIT video) that , using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the derivative of potential energy is related to force; but I cannot manage to see exactly how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a force [in 1D - the generalization in 3D is straightforward but you need vector calculus] $F(x)$ which is conservative then the potential energy is defined as

$$V(x) = - \int _{x_0}^{x} F(x')dx'$$
where $x_0$ is an arbitrary starting point.

This means, that, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, you can "eliminate" the integral by taking the derivative of the potential

$${dV \over dx} = -F(x)$$

so the condition that the derivative of the energy is $0$ means

$${dV\over dx} = 0 = F(x)$$
meaning that the total force acting on your mass is $F(x)=0$ i.e. the mass is at equilibrium (no forces are acting).

If you then wonder whether the equilibrium is *stable* (i.e., if you move a bit you come back where you started) then you need to look at the *second* derivative of the potential energy. You can check [more details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to make it sure:   " x' " denotes the derivative of x , meaning here velocity?

Comment: No, x' denotes the integration variable: it still is "position" but I already used "normal" x for the extreme of integration. Equivalently I could have written something like $V(x)=\int_{x_0}^{x} F(s)ds$ or similar. It is just to avoid confusion. I have denoted derivatives as $d/dx$

Comment: Thanks for having expalined !

Answer (score 3):

Work is defined as $F\times d$. If your force varies, then $W = \int F \cdot dx$, and you can interpret an integral as a sum of many tiny lengths. Work increases energy. When a force like gravity does work, it is increasing the kinetic energy by losing potential energy, since total energy is conserved.

If you imagine a hill, the slope of the hill tells you how much force pushes you downhill. Hills are useful analogies because the height of a hill is linearly proportional to its potential energy.